# Haskell/Yesod - Butchering use of MaybeT

Tags: haskell, monads, optional

The following is some code that is used to provide the frontend with certain parameters when rendering a form. The parameters are conditional based around what data is being changed, `getNewSaleFormOptions` provides a way of quering these options using a `GET` request and url params (ie `/sales/new?dealership=11&vehicle=2`), and another `getEditSaleFormOptions` when returning to edit, but through the entity id, ie `/sales/1` (this will pull necessary data, dealership, vehicle, from `Sale 1`).

I've tried to use `MaybeT` here to simplify a lot of the calls that return `m (Maybe a)`, though its possible i'm not using it in the most efficient way. There are lots of `MaybeT` and `runMaybeT` calls (though this might be okay), and a few spots where there is duplicated code... I'm just not sure of the best way to eliminate them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Forms.SaleForm
  ( SaleFormOptions(..)
  , getNewSaleFormOptions
  , getEditSaleFormOptions
  ) where

import           Control.Monad (join)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (MaybeT(..), runMaybeT)
import qualified Data.Aeson as Aeson
import           Data.Aeson ((.=), ToJSON)
import qualified Data.Maybe as M
import           Data.Text (Text)
import           Database.Esqueleto (SqlPersistT, get)
import           Yesod.Core (MonadHandler(..), PathPiece(..))

data SaleFormOptions = SaleFormOptions
  { saleFormOptionsCampaigns :: Maybe MarketingCampaigns
  , saleFormOptionsDiscountElegible :: Bool
  }

instance ToJSON SaleFormOptions where
  toJSON SaleFormOptions{..} =
    Aeson.object [ "campaigns" .= saleFormOptionsCampaigns
                 , "discount_elegible" .= saleFormOptionsDiscountElegible
                 ]

getNewSaleFormOptions :: MonadHandler m => Key User -> SqlPersistT m SaleFormOptions
getNewSaleFormOptions userKey = NewTenancyFormFields <$> campaigns <*> discountElegible
 where
    campaigns =
      runMaybeT (MaybeT . fetchCampaigns userKey =<< lookupIdGetParamM "dealership")

    discountElegible =
      M.fromMaybe False <$> runMaybeT (MaybeT . fmap Just . isDiscountElegible =<< lookupIdGetParamM "vehicle")

getEditSaleFormOptions
  :: MonadHandler m
  => Key User
  -> Key Sale
  -> SqlPersistT m SaleFormOptions
getEditSaleFormOptions userKey saleKey = do
  sale <- get saleKey
  EditTenancyTenantFormFields <$> fmap join (mapM (fetchCampaigns userKey) (saleDealership <$> sale))
                              <*> (M.fromMaybe False <$> mapM isDiscountElegible (saleVehicle <$> sale))

fetchCampaigns :: MonadHandler m => Key User -> Key Dealership -> SqlPersistT m (Maybe MarketingCampaigns)
fetchCampaigns userKey dealershipKey = do
  enabled <- campaignsEnabled userKey dealershipKey
  if enabled then Just <$> getCampaigns dealershipKey
             else return Nothing

isDiscountElegible :: MonadHandler m => Key Vehicle -> SqlPersistT m Bool
isDiscountElegible vehicleKey = M.fromMaybe False <$> runMaybeT checkElegible
  where
    checkElegible = do
      vehicle <- MaybeT (get vehicleKey)
      vehicleHasDiscount <$> (MaybeT . get $ vehicleManufacturer vehicle)
                         <*> pure vehicle

lookupIdGetParamM
  :: (PathPiece (Key a), MonadHandler m)
  => Text
  -> MaybeT m (Key a)
lookupIdGetParamM = MaybeT . lookupIdGetParam
```

And this is the code for `lookupIdGetParam`:

```
lookupIdGetParam :: (PathPiece (Key a), MonadHandler m) => Text -> m (Maybe (Key a))
lookupIdGetParam name = do
  mraw <- lookupGetParam name
  case mraw of
    Nothing  -> return Nothing
    Just raw -> return (fromPathPiece raw)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest these points to simplify your code:

- Make everything that returns `Maybe something` into `MaybeT`, and as close to the origin as possible. This will make composition of your functions much easier. For example:

  ```
  lookupIdGetParam :: (PathPiece (Key a), MonadHandler m) => Text -> MaybeT m (Key a)
  lookupIdGetParam name = liftM fromPathPiece (MaybeT $ lookupGetParam name)
  ```

  Notice using `MaybeT` just at `lookupGetParam`, then we don't need to duplicate `MaybeT`'s functionality in the `case` expression.

  This also helps you to avoid complicated code with two nested monads (such as `SqlPersistT m (Maybe MarketingCampaigns)`) and then complex and hard-to-read operations on them like `fmap join (mapM ...)`.
- `MaybeT . fmap Just` is equivalent to [`lift`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#v:lift).
- Whenever applicable, use functions from [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus). Not just `mzero` (which is here equivalent to `Nothing`) and `mplus`, there are also some other very useful ones such as [`mfilter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mfilter) or [`guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard). Like in:

  ```
  fetchCampaigns :: MonadHandler m => Key User -> Key Dealership -> MaybeT (SqlPersistT m) MarketingCampaigns
  fetchCampaigns userKey dealershipKey = do
    enabled <- lift $ campaignsEnabled userKey dealershipKey
    guard enabled
    lift $ getCampaigns dealershipKey
  ```
- Something to try out, I'm not sure if this will help you, but it might: Instead of a function that returns a `Bool` in a monad, return `MaybeT MyMonad ()` such that original `False` corresponds to a failure in `MaybeT` and `True` to a `()` value. To be specific, instead of `isDiscountEligible`, you could have

  ```
  checkDiscountElegible :: MonadHandler m => Key Vehicle -> MaybeT (SqlPersistT m) ()
  checkDiscountElegible vehicleKey = do
    vehicle <- MaybeT (get vehicleKey)
    hasDiscount <- vehicleHasDiscount <$> (MaybeT . get $ vehicleManufacturer vehicle)
                                      <*> pure vehicle
    guard hasDiscount
  ```

  The idea is that this will make these functions composable with the other `MaybeT ...` ones, and avoid the tedious `M.fromMaybe False <$> runMaybeT`.

  In other words, in `MaybeT m Bool` there are two failure modes: One failing within the monad, and another returning `False`. If you know from the beginning that they're both equivalent, just collapse them instead of keeping the distinction.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried to compile any of the above, so there might be syntax errors, but hopefully the meaning is clear.*